# angularJS in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, angularjs

I was wondering if anyone had any example of using AngularJS in lightning components.

I'm able to handel js code using static resource but getting problem in .cmp file how to use their CDATA is also not helpful.

Any example or sample code please help if anybody has done anything like that.

Comment: I hope this [link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura-ng) will help you out.

Comment: I had already read above given link. Thanks for help but this is not working.

Comment: Can you please try the below link .there is an open source aura library for Angular. If this doesn't work i can suggest alternate ways https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura-ng
-RedDevil